# repick random normal values less than given stadard deviation

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

To initialize weights in my tensorflow neural network I began with `tf.random_normal()`. A normal distribution around zero is what I'm seeking. To then eliminate excessively large initial weights, I switched to `tf.truncated_normal()`. Since -2.0 and +2.0 are *still* too large, I moved to `tf.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1)`, solving the problem of initial weight being too 'large.'

However, I would also like to eliminate values that are too small (i.e. too close to zero). In other words, in addition to re-picking all weights <-0.2 or >+0.2, I'd like to re-pick all weights between, for example, -0.02 and +0.02. Is there a way to do this outside of a brute force `while` loop? In other words, is there an 'inverse' `tf.truncated_normal()`?

P.S. The reason for my thinking comes from after the 27th minute of a [talk with Ilya Sutskever](http://www.thetalkingmachines.com/blog/2015/1/15/machine-learning-and-magical-thinking) where he discusses how random initializations that are too large *or* too small can prevent the network from learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `tf.constant()` variable from a numpy array by feeding numpy array into it;

```
# Create a np.array however you want, manipulate and feed
weight_1 = np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(256, 64))
weight_1[weight_1 < 0] = weight_1[weight_1 < 0] - 0.01
weight_1[weight_1 > 0] = weight_1[weight_1 > 0] + 0.01
w = tf.constant(weight_1)
```

Or you can manipulate a tensorflow tensor before `initialize_all_variables()` by its `initialized_value()` function and create a tensor from that.

```
weight_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 64], stddev=0.35),
                       name="weight_1")
# code below will give you the weight_1 * 2
weights = tf.Variable(weight_1.initialized_value() * 2.0)
```

And you can somehow math your way out to values you need with that, but numpy way seems much more easier.

Also what you are doing looks a lot like [xavier initialization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer), which you can use as following;

```
weight_1 = tf.get_variable('weight_1', shape=(256, 100),
                initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

Comment: `np.random.randint()` takes integer arguments, so `np.random.randint(0.01, 0.02, size=(256, 64))` returns zeros. I think what you want is `np.random.randint(100, 200, size=(10, 10))/1000`, but those values are not normally distributed. The `tf.Variable(weight_1.initialized_value() * 2.0)` will just increase the std dev of the weights; it doesn't eliminate small values. I've heard about Xavier Initialization. I'll look into that. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah I meant to say `numpy.random.normal` and then do some smart math stuff on it to get values you wanted. But my brain doesn't work today, so I've left it like that. And randint with floats, yup just brain farted, will fix it thanks.

Comment: I see what you did with `weight_1[weight_1 < 0] = weight_1[weight_1 < 0] - 0.01`. Clever. It's not _exactly_ what I was requesting, but it's pretty close, so +1. [Understanding Xavier Initialization In Deep Neural Networks](https://prateekvjoshi.com/2016/03/29/understanding-xavier-initialization-in-deep-neural-networks/) gives a pretty great explanation, so I'm thinking that's what I want. I ran your code and it looks good, but I'm not yet sure. Allow me to reflect. Thank you.